# Updating 'Parent' entity instead of creating it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I'm listing a series of items and i want top implement an option where you click and it add a child object for that entity, let me explain:

```
    public class SupportItem
   {
    [Display(Name = "Categoría")]
    [ConcurrencyCheck, Required]

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Key, HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]       
    public int SupportItemId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [ConcurrencyCheck,Required]

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Display(Name = "Descripción Corta")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

     [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public virtual SupportItem Father { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripción detallada")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required]
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public bool Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now as u can see, this entity has a Father which is of type SupporItem. Now what I want to do is to list them all and add an option which will let you easily add a child for that item you select, heres the view definition:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.SupportItem>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "IndexSupportItems";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Index Support Items</h2>

    <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Crear nuevo item principal", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="Grid">
    <tr>
    <th>
        Tipo
    </th>
    <th>
        Nombre
    </th>
    <th>
        Descripción
    </th>
    <th> 
        Acciones
    </th>                
    </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
    <tr>
    <td>@item.Type</td>
    @if(item.Children)
    {
    <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name,"ListChildren", new{item.SupportItemId})</td>
    }
    else
    {<td>@item.Name</td>

    }
    <td>@item.Description</td>
        <td>
       @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteSupportItem", new{item.Father.SupportItemId})<br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Add subitem sub-item","AddSubitem", new{item.SupportItemId})<br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit","EditSupportItem", new{item.SupportItemId})    
    </td>

</tr>
    }

    </table>
```

Now as you can see, the action link for doing this points to a method called AddSubitem, which is implemented as follows:

```
    public ViewResult AddSubitem(int supportItemId)
    {
        SupportItem child = new SupportItem() { Father = repo.GetSupportItemFromId(supportItemId) };

        return View(child);
    }
```

As you can see, I recieve a supportItemId which is the id from the parent entitity (the one to whom i want to add the new child), find it on my database context and create the new object and point the Father object i just found. After doing that the view it returns is this:

```
    @model Domain.Entities.SupportItem

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "AddSubitem";
    }

    <h2>AddSubitem</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Support Item</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LongDescription)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LongDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LongDescription)
    </div>



            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

In this view, the user will set some of the variables such as name and description and then submit the object so I can persist it to the database, **the problem is** the object I get from this view has its fathers id as its own id and the Father attribute is null thus i end up updating the Father object to which i want to add a child with this method:

public bool SaveSupportItem(SupportItem supportItem)
        {
            bool retorno = false;

```
        if (supportItem.SupportItemId == 0)
        {
            context.SupportItems.Add(supportItem);
            supportItem.Father.Children = true;
            retorno = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SupportItem itemDB = context.SupportItems.Find(supportItem.SupportItemId);
            if (itemDB != null)
            {
                itemDB.Name = supportItem.Name;
                itemDB.Type = supportItem.Type;
                itemDB.LongDescription = supportItem.LongDescription;
                itemDB.Description = supportItem.Description;
                retorno = true;
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        return retorno;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? why can't  I create a new object?

Thanks for taking the time and reading this, any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: First, you will not be able to edit something that doesn't exist. Also what is the relationship between `Father` and `SupportItem`? Is it `one-to-one` or `one-to-many`

Comment: The problem is the object I create gets lost somehow on the createObject view. The relation between Father and support item is: each supportItem can o cannot have a father which is of type support item also, its defined on this attribute:                 [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public virtual SupportItem Father { get; set; }

Comment: what is the relationship between `Father` and `SupportItem`? Is it `one-to-one` or `one-to-many`?

Comment: it is one-to-one, each support item can have only one father

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this:

**Add this to your SupportItem class**

```
public class SupportItem
{
  [Key]
  [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
  [ForeignKey("Father"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]       
  public int SupportItemId { get; set; }

  public virtual Father Father { get; set; }

  ...................
  ...................
}
```

Then change:

`@Html.ActionLink("Add subitem sub-item","AddSubitem", new{item.SupportItemId})<br />`

to

`@Html.ActionLink("Add subitem sub-item","AddSubitem", "Controller Name here" new{SupportItemId = @Model.FatherId})<br />`

Also because we need FatherId here `new{SupportItemId = @Model.FatherId}`, the `ActionLink` needs to be in lets say Father view e.g in Father Details where only single Father is current or something as you have to associate the supportItem with to specific father.

Your controller might look like this, assuming that you are using a ViewModel:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateSuppo(int supportItemId)
    {
        var model = new CreateSupportItemViewModel ();
        model.SupportItemId= supportItemId;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateSupportItemViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var father= db.Fathers.Single(f => f.FatherId == viewModel.SupportItemId);
            var supportItem= new SupportItem();
            supportItem.Name = viewModel.Name;
            ....................
            .................
            father.SupportItems.Add(supportItem);

            db.SaveChanges();               
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```